# Ionic / Angular JS - Get specific values from Reverse Geolocation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am building an App using Ionic / Angular JS. In a specific tab, the app has the ability to fill some form fields automatically like Street Name, Street Number, etc. **My problem is that, in some situations the Street Number for example is not available and `data[0].address_components[0].long_name` fills the Street Name instead.**

Here is the code that I use:

```
.controller('PetitionsCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaCamera, $log, $ionicLoading, $http, $timeout, $compile, Upload) {


  $scope.getLocation = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      templateUrl: 'loading.html',
      hideOnStateChange: true
    });
      var posOptions = {timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
      $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function (position) {
        $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $scope.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        $scope.pLat = {value: $scope.lat};
        $scope.pLng = {value: $scope.lng};

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.lng);
        var request = {
          latLng: latlng
        };

        geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (data[0] != null) {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.pStreet = {value: data[0].address_components[1].long_name};
                $scope.pNumber = {value: data[0].address_components[0].long_name};
                $scope.pCity = {value: data[0].address_components[2].long_name};
                $scope.pAddress = {value: data[0].formatted_address};
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
              });
            } else {
              $log.log("Adresa indisponibila");
              setTimeout(function () {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
              }, 500);
            }
          }
        })
      });
    };
})
```

Here is an example response from Google:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How can I alter my code so it checks the `"types"` value before reading a value and leaves it empty if not available. To be more speicifc, instead of using `data[0].address_components[0].long_name` to get the street number, I would like to get if `"types"` vale is `"street_number"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have understood is that if the types value is equal to `street_number` you want to get the value otherwise you want to put empty as a value `''`

```
geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (data[0] != null) {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.pStreet = {value: data[0].address_components[1].long_name};
                $scope.pNumber = {value: data[0].address_components[0].types[0] === 'street_number' ? data[0].address_components[0].long_name : ''};
                $scope.pCity = {value: data[0].address_components[2].long_name};
                $scope.pAddress = {value: data[0].formatted_address};
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
              });
            } else {
              $log.log("Adresa indisponibila");
              setTimeout(function () {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
              }, 500);
            }
          }
        })
```

Comment: I have to on geolocation in my application. whenever I will go to particular page pop up should come to Allow geolocation or Deny
so this code is usefull for that or can you suggest me how to add this popup to ask allow geolocation..

Comment: As I have stated in my answer, this is not correct because you are checking just the first element on the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over result set to find a match like:

```
Angular.forEach(data[0].address_components, function(val, index){ 
   if (val.type[0]=='street_number') {
      $scope.pNumber = {value: val.long_name};
   }
});
```

You can use this code to find any other value like `city` or `country` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Ryad.iv answer is just checking the first string in the array. For this to work properly you have to check all the elements of the array.

```
geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (data[0] != null) {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.pStreet = {value: data[0].address_components[1].long_name};
                $scope.pNumber = {value: data[0].address_components[0].types.indexOf('street_number') !== -1 ? data[0].address_components[0].long_name : ''};
                $scope.pCity = {value: data[0].address_components[2].long_name};
                $scope.pAddress = {value: data[0].formatted_address};
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
              });
            } else {
              $log.log("Adresa indisponibila");
              setTimeout(function () {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
              }, 500);
            }
          }
        })
```

That's the good way of checking this. With the other answer, if `street_name` is the second position of the array you will not be inserting it correctly.

Hope it helps

Comment: You can not infer that the array of types when it contains a `street_number` will always be a single element array with `street_number` in first position.

Comment: You don't know that. And if today that's how google do it and tomorrow it changes the implementation your app is broken. Is stupid to make it that way and I'm sorry but that's a very bad answer. I'm sure you have downvoted my answer, but believe it or not is the correct one.

Comment: No good programmer in the entire world that have worked with 3rd party apis would check it your way. It's a very poor validation.

Comment: I don't have to prove anything. In fact I'm pretty sure google will never respond with an array with length > 1 if `street_number` is in it. I'm just telling that your way of checking is poor and teaching someone to do it like this is unfair. Also, your downvote was a misuse of the stackoverflow voting feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129429/discussion-between-ryad-iv-and-jorge).